# com.facebook.fresco is causing crash in the React Native app

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, expo, gif

My react native version is 0.71.5.

I want to add gif to android. I added the code below to build.gradle

```
    implementation("com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.5.0")
```

After adding this code, my app crashes when I run `react-native run-android`.

The error is:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not open cp_proj generic class cache for build file '/Users/student/Projects/azerbaijan-railways-app/android/app/build.gradle' (/Users/student/.gradle/caches/7.5.1/scripts/3s1f8g1gnokk1i464s53rx1dg).
   > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 64
```

dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
    implementation("com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.5.0")

    implementation("androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0")
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"


    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}
```

I tried to change the version, but it didn't solve the problem.